# Sets is not Equivalent to $sets^{op}$

Tags: category-theory

How do we show that the category of sets is not equivalent to it's opposite. I know we use $\emptyset$ and singletons to show that they are not isomorphic.

The definition of equivalence that I am using is that there are two functors $F:sets\rightarrow sets^{op}$ and $G:sets^{op}\rightarrow sets$ such that $FG$ is naturally isomorphic to $1_{sets}$ and $GF$ is naturally isomorphic to $1_{sets^{op}}$

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are lots of non-invertible morphisms $1 \to X$. But every morphism $X \to \emptyset$ is invertible. Hence $\mathbf{Set}$ is not equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}^\mathrm{op}$ either.

Comment: Thanks but why does that follow? Why is the number of invertible maps some sort of invaraint under equivalence?

Comment: Assuming $\mathbf{Set}$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}^\mathrm{op}$, if the terminal object in $\mathbf{Set}$ has some equivalence-invariant property, then the initial object in $\mathbf{Set}$ has the dual property. This is not the case, so the initial assumption must be false.

Comment: Ok but in order to do this I would need to show that the number of morphisms is an equivalence invariant right?

Comment: I didn't say it was an invariant. This is the invariant property: "every morphism $X \to \emptyset$ is invertible".

Comment: Ok sorry I misunderstood, so I need to show that that is an invariant under equivalence then right?